# Grep Regular Expression in Cygwin

Tags: regex, grep

I am using Cygwin on Windows. I want to extract all the lines from a file which contain exactly 9 letters in the name.

To do this, I am using:

```
cat filename.txt | grep -P "[a-z]{9}"
```

however this is also returning words of different case and lengths greater than 9.

I have even set the environment variable, LC_ALL to C.

I am able to make this work though:

cat filename.txt | grep -P "^[a-z]*[a-z]$"

And this displays only words with lowercase characters.

Please note that I am running the commands in Cygwin and I have observed that there are certain differences between Cygwin and a Linux Distro. The commands do not work the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
cat filename.txt | grep -P "^[a-z]{9}$"
```

> ^ = beginning of string
>
> $ = end of string

Your regex returns all words containing lower-case alphabets which have a length which is a multiple of 9.

Comment: Thanks. But as I said before, it is not limiting the charset to [a-z] only. It is even printing words like, tamara125. Now, you can see, it has digits at the end as well. I have set the LC_ALL env to C already.